# SQL Server bak file cannot be found

Tags: sql-server, backup

Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I created a backup file of a database in a `backupData.bak` file.

I specified the path to C: drive to make it simple: `C:\backupData.bak`

I get a message

> The back of the database XXXX completed successfully

However, when I go to the `C:\` drive, I don't see this backup file.

I am not trying to restore this backup file. I am trying to copy this backup file into a USB memory, but I read somewhere that I shouldn't make a backup file directly from SQL Server Management Studio into a USB memory, so I am doing it one step at a time.

How can I make this backup file visible so I can copy it to my USB memory?
I tried changing the file permission of `C:\` drive and added `NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER` and gave it a full control, but it did not make this backup file appear.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Is this SQL Server running on a *remote* machine? If so: the backup file is being created **on that remote machine** in its `C:\` drive - **NOT** on your local computer's `C:\` drive ....

Comment: Is there any way to check if it is running on a remote machine? I am working on this computer of someone else's, and this person said he is not sure...

Comment: Do you know the name of the computer you're working on? And don't you know the name of the SQL Server you seem to be allowed to manage???

Comment: I do not know the name of the computer I am working on.. name of the SQL server? Like the login user name and password?

Comment: How do you connect to SQL Server?? What is the server/instance name you're using?? If it's `.`, `(local)` or `localhost`, then it's your local machine - anything else is likely a remote computer (some server on the network somewhere)